# How To Check available port in pc?

Tags: java, serial-port

i want list of available port in pc i am using this code in java but mot getting  response
i import javax.comm liabrary . please short out my problem

Thanks

```
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier;


public class CommPortLister {

  /** Simple test program. */
  public static void main(String[] ap) {
    new CommPortLister().list();
  }

  /** Ask the Java Communications API * what ports it thinks it has. */
  protected void list() {
    // get list of ports available on this particular computer,
    // by calling static method in CommPortIdentifier.
    Enumeration pList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    // Process the list.
    while (pList.hasMoreElements()) {
      CommPortIdentifier cpi = (CommPortIdentifier) pList.nextElement();
      System.out.print("Port " + cpi.getName() + " ");
      if (cpi.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
        System.out.println("is a Serial Port: " + cpi);
      } else if (cpi.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL) {
        System.out.println("is a Parallel Port: " + cpi);
      } else {
        System.out.println("is an Unknown Port: " + cpi);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Discovering_comm_ports) library successfully to do the same thing your trying to do .Equivalent code using RXTX:

```
import gnu.io.*;
    static void listPorts()
    {
        java.util.Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier> portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        while ( portEnum.hasMoreElements() ) 
        {
            CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = portEnum.nextElement();
            System.out.println(portIdentifier.getName()  +  " - " +  getPortTypeName(portIdentifier.getPortType()) );
        }        
    }

    static String getPortTypeName ( int portType )
    {
        switch ( portType )
        {
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_I2C:
                return "I2C";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL:
                return "Parallel";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_RAW:
                return "Raw";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_RS485:
                return "RS485";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL:
                return "Serial";
            default:
                return "unknown type";
        }
}
```